# do() function In R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have gone through different sites to understand about do() function in R. However, I did not the concept clearly . Could some one please help me to under stand it, giving below example for reference.

Example:

```
by_cyl <- group_by(mtcars, cyl)
do(by_cyl, head(., 2))
```

But did not understand why they passed single dot into head function inside do() ?

Comment: `do` will iterate the inner code once for each group; in this example, three groups. The dot `.` represents one group's data in that iteration. Try `do(by_cyl, { browser(); head(., 2); })` and when you get to the `Browse[2]` prompt, see what `.` looks like.

Comment: Will note that `do` has been labeled "superceded" as of `dplyr` 1.0.0. The documentation states that you can use a combination of `summarize()`, `nest_by()`, and `across()` to accomplish the same things as `do`

Comment: I seem to recall that it was the only way to do certain group functions in dplyr pre-1.0.0, and further I recall (without proof, sorry) seeing warnings that it was not always the best way to do things. I have old code riddled with it, and ... am one-by-one replacing `do` with other methods (that are arguably faster and more readable/maintainable). If you're trying to learn about `do` because you need to do something, then perhaps you can ask about the "something" in order to get a more up-to-date tidyverse recommendation.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you very much for detailed explanation :)